# How to use data obtained from DB as values in add_argument() when the Flask app starts?

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, flask-restx

I have the following project structure for a Flask app using `flask-restx`

```
.
├── app
│   ├── extensions.py
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── pv_dimensioning
│       ├── controller.py
│       ├── __init__.py
│       ├── models
│       │   ├── dto.py
│       │   ├── __init__.py
│       │   └── vendor_models.py
│       ├── services
│       │   ├── calculator.py
│       │   ├── database.py
│       │   ├── data.py
│       │   ├── db_crud.py
│       │   ├── __init__.py
│       │   └── processor.py
│       └── utils
│           ├── decode_verify_jwt.py
│           ├── decorator.py
│           └── __init__.py
├── config.py
├── main.py
├── package.json
├── package-lock.json
├── Pipfile
├── Pipfile.lock
├── README.md
├── serverless.yml
└── tests
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── test_calculator.py
    ├── test_config.py
    └── test_processor.py
```

In `controller.py`, I am adding the `add_argument()` statements and parsing them in the api routes. In one of the `add_argument()` statement, I would like to add `choices` for the user. For getting the choices, I am querying from the database and getting a `list` of values available. I then convert this `list` to a `tuple`, assign it to a variable, and pass it as `choices` parameter in the `add_argument()`

**My codes:**

**data.py**

```
from ..models.vendor_models import AdminVendor

def data(app):
    values = AdminVendor.query.all()
    v = [value.name for value in values]
    return {'v': tuple(v)}
```

**controller.py**

```
from flask_restx import Resource, reqparse

parser = reqparse.RequestParser()

parser.add_argument(
    "vendor",
    choices=vendors, # <--- The values of v should be added here
    help="Select the vendor"
)

@ns.route("/")
class UserOutput(Resource):
    @ns.doc(
        "Get calculated response",
        responses={
            200: "Values returned",
            400: "Validation Error",
            403: "Not authorized"
        },
    )
    @ns.expect(parser, validation=True)
    def get(self):
        args = parser.parse_args()
        return DimensionCalculator.inputs(**args), 200
```

where `ns` is the `namespace`.

My `__init__.py` file in the `app` folder is as follows:

```
from flask import Flask

from .extensions import cors, db, ma

def create_app(app_config):
    app = Flask(__name__)

    app.config.from_object(app_config)

    register_blueprints(app)
    register_extensions(app)
    return app

def register_extensions(app):
    cors.init_app(app)
    db.init_app(app)
    ma.init_app(app)

def register_blueprints(app):
    from .pv_dimensioning import dimensioning_blueprint
    app.register_blueprint(dimensioning_blueprint)
```

and the entry point to the app is `main.py`

```
import os

from app import create_app
from app.extensions import db
from app.pv_dimensioning.services.data import data
from config import config_by_name

config_name = os.getenv("FLASK_CONFIG") or "default"
app_config = config_by_name[config_name]
app = create_app(app_config)

db.create_all(app=app)

with app.app_context():
    v = data(app)

print(v)
```

The output of `print(v)` is as follows:

```
{'v': ('Solarmodul Canadian Solar HiKu CS3L-370MS 370Wp', 'Solarmodul Longi LR4-60HIH-370M, 370Wp', 'Solarmodul Solar Fabrik mono S3 - Halfcut 360Wp', 'Solarmodul Energetica e.Classic M HC black - 360Wp', 'Solarmodul Yingli YL280P-29b-YGE 60 Cell Series 2 - poly, 280Wp', 'Solarmodul Suntech Power STP370S-B60/Wnh, 370Wp', 'Solarmodul AXITEC AXIworldpremium X HC AC-340MH/120S, 340Wp', 'Solarmodul Longi LR4-72HIH-440M, 440Wp', 'Solarmodul Seraphim SRP-330-BMB-DG 330Wp', 'Solarmodul Sharp NU-JD 440Wp')}
```

I want these values of `v` to be used in `controller.py` in the `'vendor'` argument.

I have tried getting the values of `v` from `main.py` by adding `from main import v` in the `controller.py`, but it shows the following error

`ImportError: cannot import name 'v' from 'main'`

What is the mistake that I am doing?

Comment: I don't have a solution right now, but the import error makes sense as v is created in main.py after create_app has been called, thus by the time you try  to import v, it does not exist, if my understanding of this is right.

Comment: I tried using `flask-caching` as an extension, and that too isn't working

Answer (score 1):

I'm not an expert on `flask_restx`, but from my understanding, the `choices` argument takes an iterable so you should simply be able to pass in the return value of your `data` function.

#### data.py

```py
from ..models.vendor_models import AdminVendor

def data():
    values = AdminVendor.query.all()
    v = [value.name for value in values]
    return {'v': tuple(v)}
```

#### controller.py

```py
from flask_restx import Resource, reqparse
from .services.data import data 

parser = reqparse.RequestParser()

parser.add_argument(
    "vendor",
    choices=data()['v'],  
    help="Select the vendor")
```

Regarding the import error, as Mindslave points out that is most likely a circular import error see this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/744403/4028718) for a bit more detail. Generally these can be avoided by moving the import from the top of the module to within a function/class, e.g:

```py
from flask_restx import Resource, reqparse



def load_parser():
    from .services.data import data # avoid circular import

    parser = reqparse.RequestParser()
    parser.add_argument(
        "vendor",
        choices=data()['v'],  
        help="Select the vendor")
    return parser

parse = load_parser()
```

As a side note, be aware that `reqparse` is scheduled to be removed from flask_restx, so might be worth considering a different option before you get too embedded with it:

> Warning The whole request parser part of Flask-RESTX is slated for
> removal and will be replaced by documentation on how to integrate with
> other packages that do the input/output stuff better (such as
> marshmallow). This means that it will be maintained until 2.0 but
> consider it deprecated. Don’t worry, if you have code using that now
> and wish to continue doing so, it’s not going to go away any time too
> soon.

source: https://flask-restx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/parsing.html

Comment: Hey, this actually doesn't work. I tried that too, and it gives a context application error. I added the `data()` to the app doing `with app.app_context()`, it still gives the same context error

Comment: ah, I missed that you were using the `app.context` in your `main.py`. You should be able to do something similar, but importing `v` from main rather than data in the load_parser function.

Comment: I tried adding `from main import v` in a function in `controller.py` and when I run the code, it still gives me the same error `ImportError: cannot import name 'v' from 'main'`